# MySQL encoding issue

Tags: mysql, encoding

For some reason, my mysql table is converting single and double quotes into strange characters. E.g

```
"aha"
```

is changed into:

```
â€œahaâ€
```

How can I fix this, or detect this in PHP and decode everything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of your mysql client and your server don't match. Use [SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html) to match the character set of the connection to the one used in your PHP files.

Comment: Which character set do I need to use?

Comment: Using SET NAMES 'latin1' fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the UTF-8 encoded string `“aha”` (binary 0xE2809C 0x61 0x68 0x61 0xE2809D) is interpreted with [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). There this byte sequence represents the character sequence `â€œahaâ€`.