# Problem with MySQL Encoding

Tags: mysql

I've asked this question before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747179/mysql-encoding-issue), however that solution didn't fix it when I looked closely. This is the problem.

For some reason, my mysql table is converting single and double quotes into strange characters. E.g

```
"aha"
```

is changed into:

```
â€œahaâ€
```

How can I fix this, or detect this in PHP and decode everything??

Previously i tried doing this query right after connecting to MySQL:

```
$sql="SET NAMES 'latin1'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

But that no longer has any effect. I'm seeing strings such as:

```
 â€œahaâ€ (for "aha")
Itâ€™s (for "its")
```

etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer to your original question, your input is actually in UTF-8, but the output you're seeing looks wrong because your output terminal and/or browser is set to the (single byte) character encoding "Windows 1252".

If you just make sure that your *output* is also set to UTF-8 then everything should be fine.

See [Quotation marks turn to question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760113/quotation-marks-turn-to-question-marks)

Comment: Genius. Adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> below the <html> tag fixed it.

Comment: great, glad it helped.  I wish I knew why someone else down-voted it, though :(